# Python & Pandas: Parsing JSONs in a loop

Tags: python, json, pandas

With Python I'm pulling a nested json, and I'm seeking to parse it via a loop and write the data to a csv. The structure of the json is below. The values I'm after are in the `"view"` list, labeled `"user_id"` and `"message"'

```
{
  "view": [
    {
      "id": 109205,
      "user_id": 6354,
      "parent_id": null,
      "created_at": "2020-11-03T23:32:49Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-11-03T23:32:49Z",
      "rating_count": null,
      "rating_sum": null,
      **"message": "message text",**
      "replies": [

      # json continues
  ],
}
```

After some study and assistance from [this helpful tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-do-i-extract-nested-data-in-python-4e7bed37566a) I was able to structure requests like this:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "URL"
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer KEY'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()


print(data['view'][0]['user_id'])
print(data['view'][0]['message'])
```

Which successfully prints the outputs `6354` and `"message test"`.

Now....how would I approach capturing all the user id's and messages from the json to a csv with Pandas?

Comment: Well you have some options, you don't even necessarily need pandas to do this. You could just use the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), looping over the data and writing lines for each entry. If you have your heart set on pandas you'll likely need the [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Both are the links to the docs where you should find helpful examples and whatnot to get you where you are trying to go.

Comment: Addendum, to write a DataFrame as a csv there is the [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method. If you run into further issues update your question with what you have tried and what difficulties or errors you have encountered.